# react native get TextInput value

Tags: react-native

I am stuck with a very simple problem. I have login form with username, password and button. In my button handler, I try to get the textinput value. But always get undefined value. Am I missing something?

```
render() {
        <ExScreen
          headerColor={this.state.headerColor}
          scrollEnabled={this.state.enableScroll}
          style={styles.container} >
          <View >
            <View  >
              <View style={[styles.inputContainer]} >
                <TextInput
                  ref= "username"
                  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                  value={this.state.username}
                />
              </View>
 <Button style={{color: 'white', marginTop: 30, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'white', marginLeft: 20*vw, marginRight: 20*vw, height: 40, padding: 10}} 
             onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this)}>
              Sign In
            </Button>   
...
 _handlePress(event) {
    var username=this.refs.username.value;
```

Answer (score 84):

The quick and less optimized way to do this is by using arrow function inside your onChangeText callback, by passing `username` as your argument in your onChangeText callback.

```
<TextInput
    ref= {(el) => { this.username = el; }}
    onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}
    value={this.state.username}
/>
```

then in your `_handlePress` method

```
_handlePress(event) {
    let username=this.state.username;
}
```

---

But this has several drawbacks!!!

1. On every render of this component a new arrow function is created.
2. If the child component is a PureComponent it will force re-renders unnecessarily, this causes huge performance issue especially when dealing with large lists, table, or component iterated over large numbers. [More on this in React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Best practice is to use a handler like `handleInputChange` and bind ```this`` in the constructor.

```
...
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

...
handleChange(event = {}) {
  const name = event.target && event.target.name;
  const value = event.target && event.target.value;

  this.setState([name]: value);
}
...

render() {
  ...
  <TextInput
    name="username"
    onChangeText={this.handleChange}
    value={this.state.username}
  />
  ...
}

...
```

---

Or if you are using es6 class property shorthand which autobinds `this`.  But this has drawbacks, when it comes to testing and performance. [Read More Here](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1)

```
...
handleChange= (event = {}) => {
  const name = event.target && event.target.name;
  const value = event.target && event.target.value;

  this.setState([name]: value);
}
...

render() {
  ...
  <TextInput
    name="username"
    onChangeText={this.handleChange}
    value={this.state.username}
  />
  ...
}

...
```

Comment: This works although adding the `ref` prop gave me a warning: "Stateless function components cannot be given refs..." However, it is not needed for this solution.

Comment: yeah i have updated the example with the new way of declaring a ref, but in this example ref isn't really being used so could be omitted.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting upvoted so much. Isn't it bad practice to set state inside of the component's render function?

Comment: i think since the setState is being done in the onChangeText callback it is acceptable, as its not being called in the render block, i am following the react native text input example https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#examples , maybe they are wrong???

Comment: This is not a optimized solution because you don't want to re-render whole component on every change text..

Comment: @ferndopolis *"Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components"*

Comment: Why doesn't handleChange re render the component if it changes its state as well?

Comment: In my case, I found that I had to change the middle answer from this `this.setState([name]: value);` to this `this.setState({[name]: value});` and `value={this.state.username}` to `defaultValue={this.state.username}`.

Comment: The second method gives me undefined names and values, as I've demonstrated with this code: constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(event = {}) {
        const name = event.target && event.target.name;
        const value = event.target && event.target.value;
        alert(name);
        alert(value);
        this.setState({[name]: value});
    }

Comment: `On every render of this component a new arrow function is created.` Creating an arrow function every render is, by itself, not a real issue. It's extremely cheap. Even when creating hundreds of them.

Answer (score 24):

You should use **States** to store the value of input fields.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html

- To update state values use `setState`

> onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({username: value})}

- and get input value like this

> this.state.username

Sample code

```js
export default class Login extends Component {
        
    state = {
        username: 'demo',
        password: 'demo'
    };
    
    <Text style={Style.label}>User Name</Text>
    <TextInput
        style={Style.input}
        placeholder="UserName"
        onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({username: value})}
        value={this.state.username}
    />
    
    <Text style={Style.label}>Password</Text>
    <TextInput
        style={Style.input}
        placeholder="Password"
        onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({password: value})}
        value={this.state.password}
    />

    <Button
        title="LOGIN"
        onPress={() => 
            {
                if(this.state.username.localeCompare('demo')!=0){
                    ToastAndroid.show('Invalid UserName',ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                    return;
                }

                if(this.state.password.localeCompare('demo')!=0){
                    ToastAndroid.show('Invalid Password',ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                    return;
                }

                //Handle LOGIN

            }
        }
    />
```

Answer (score 19):

In React Native 0.43: (Maybe later than 0.43 is OK.)

```
_handlePress(event) {
    var username= this.refs.username._lastNativeText;
```

[image]

Comment: This seems not fully fit your needs. If you type in the inputfield "asdf", and request _lastNatRiveText, I got only "asd". Seems there is a delay of one character (lastone is allways missed)

Comment: This works. Thank you for actually answering the question.

Answer (score 17):

If you are like me and doesn't want to use or pollute state for one-off components here's what I did:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Text, TextInput } from "react-native";
   
export default class Registration extends Component {
  _register = () => {
    const payload = {
      firstName: this.firstName,
      /* other values */
    }
    
    console.log(payload)
  }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <RegisterLayout>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Register
        </Text>

        <TextInput
          placeholder="First Name"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.firstName = text} />

        {/*More components...*/}

        <CustomButton
          backgroundColor="steelblue"
          handlePress={this._register}>
          Submit
        </CustomButton>
     </RegisterLayout>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this, seems to work, doesn't seem super hacky, and doesn't require refs or state.

Comment: `InputText` is `TextInput` I guess, or did I miss something?

Comment: This is one of the few examples that showcase the uncontrolled input approach. I like it as it isn't causing unnecessary re-renders by calling `setState` each time the input change. If you don't need to do something special for each change, but just need the text value when the "Submit" button is pressed this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 8):

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  state = { username: '', password: '' }

  onChangeText = (key, val) => {
    this.setState({ [key]: val})
  }
  
  render() { 
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Login Form</Text>
          <TextInput
            placeholder='Username'
            onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('username', val)}
            style={styles.input}
          />
          <TextInput
            placeholder='Password'
            onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('password', val)}
            style={styles.input}
            secureTextEntry={true}
          />      
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting answers, it is unhelpful just to provide code. It is important to explain what your code does and how it fixes the issue at hand :)

Comment: refs? how about refs?

Answer (score 8):

This work for me

```
    <Form>

    <TextInput
    style={{height: 40}}
    placeholder="userName"
    onChangeText={(text) => this.userName = text}
    />

    <TextInput
    style={{height: 40}}
    placeholder="Password"
    onChangeText={(text) => this.Password = text}
    />


    <Button 
    title="Sign in!" 
    onPress={this._signInAsync} 
    />

    </Form>
```

and

```
  _signInAsync = async () => {
        console.log(this.userName)
        console.log(this.Password) 
  };
```

Comment: This works pretty well! +1 for not messing with state

Answer (score 5):

Please take care on how to use setState(). The correct form is

```
this.setState({
      Key: Value,
    });
```

And so I would do it as follows:

```
onChangeText={(event) => this.setState({username:event.nativeEvent.text})}
...    
var username=this.state.username;
```

Comment: If the above doesn't work, try this: 
onChangeText={(event) => this.setState({username: event.nativeEvent.text})

Comment: I get 'undefined is not an object (evaluating event.nativeEvent.text)'

Comment: .. it does however work if I use the `onChange` event rather than the `onChangeText` event

Comment: with ES6 you can write ```this.setState({ foo })``` if the key and value are ```foo```, more here: http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand so in the above example this would be right ```onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}```

Comment: `onChange` receives the event object as its parameter while `onChangeText` receives the changed text string as its parameter.

Comment: @andreaswienes: This works for me. thanks.
`onChange={(event) => this.setState({password: event.nativeEvent.text})}`

Comment: This saves my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Try **Console log the object** and you will find your entered text inside nativeEvent.text

example:

```js
handelOnChange = (enteredText) => {
    console.log(enteredText.nativeEvent.text)
}
render()
return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <TextInput
            onChange={this.handelOnChange}
        >
</SafeAreaView>

)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state ={
            commentMsg: ''         
        }
    }

 onPress = () => {
          alert("Hi " +this.state.commentMsg)
      }

 <View style={styles.sendCommentContainer}>

     <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        multiline={true}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({commentMsg: text})}
        placeholder ='Comment'/>

       <Button onPress={this.onPress} 
           title="OK!"
           color="#841584"
        />

  </TouchableOpacity>

</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do it.

```
this.state={f_name:""};

textChangeHandler = async (key, val) => {
    await this.setState({ [key]: val });
}

<Textfield onChangeText={val => this.textChangeHandler('f_name', val)}>
```

Answer (score 2):

**React Native Latest -> Simple and easy solution using state based approach.**

```
const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState(""); 

<TextInput
          value={userEmail}
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="steelblue"
          onChangeText={(userEmail) => setUserEmail(userEmail)}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Every thing is OK for me by this procedure:

```
<Input onChangeText={this.inputOnChangeText} />
```

and also:

```
inputOnChangeText = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    username: e
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the text state, why not use that directly?

```
_handlePress(event) {
  var username=this.state.text;
```

Of course the variable naming could be more descriptive than 'text' but your call.

Answer (score 0):

There is huge difference between `onChange` and `onTextChange` prop of `<TextInput />`. Don't be like me and use `onTextChange` which returns `string` and don't use `onChange` which returns full objects.

I feel dumb for spending like 1 hour figuring out where is my value.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to make a new function for taht.
just make a new useState and use it in onchange.

```
const UselessTextInput = () => {
  const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState("Useless Text");
  const [number, onChangeNumber] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={text}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeNumber}
        value={number}
        placeholder="useless placeholder"
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code worked for me. What I was missing was I was not passing 'this' in button action:

```
 onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this)}>
--------------

  _handlePress(event) {
console.log('Pressed!');

 var username = this.state.username;
 var password = this.state.password;

 console.log(username);
 console.log(password);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

      <TextInput
      ref="usr"
      style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 , marginTop: 10 , padding : 10 , marginLeft : 5 , marginRight : 5 }}
      placeHolder= "Enter username "
      placeholderTextColor = '#a52a2a'

      returnKeyType = {"next"}
      autoFocus = {true}
      autoCapitalize = "none"
      autoCorrect = {false}
      clearButtonMode = 'while-editing'
      onChangeText={(text) => {
          this.setState({username:text});
        }}
      onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
     this.refs.psw.focus();

      }}
      />

      <TextInput
      ref="psw"
      style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 , marginTop: 10,marginLeft : 5 , marginRight : 5}}
      placeholder= "Enter password"
      placeholderTextColor = '#a52a2a'
      autoCapitalize = "none"
      autoCorrect = {false}
      returnKeyType = {'done'}
      secureTextEntry = {true}
      clearButtonMode = 'while-editing'
      onChangeText={(text) => {
          this.setState({password:text});
        }}
      />

      <Button
        style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'blue'}}
        onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this)}>
        Login
      </Button>

      </View>
    );``
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

User in the init of class:

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        email: ''
    }
}
```

Then in some function:

`handleSome = () => {
        console.log(this.state.email)
   };`

And in the input:

`<TextInput onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}/>`

Answer (score -5):

Did you try

```
var username=this.state.username;
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. You should always use this.setState({...}) as @andreaswienes does.