# Get TextInput Value and Checkbox state in React native

Tags: javascript, checkbox, react-native, textinput

I want to retrieve the input value of username & password and the checkbox status. I have found this related question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913338/react-native-get-textinput-value). But when try to implement this got error

> 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.username')

Can anyone help me to retrieve input value and checkbox state as I am new to React-native

Code:

```
var CheckBox = require('react-native-checkbox');
var Button = require('react-native-button');

var reactnative = React.createClass({

render: function() {
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>

    <Text style={styles.signin}>Sign In</Text>

    <TextInput style={styles.logininput} ref= "username" onChangeText={(event) => this.setState({username:event.nativeEvent.text})} value={this.state.username}/>

    <TextInput style={styles.logininput} value="Password"/>

    <CheckBox label='Remeber Me' checked = {false} onClick={this._CheckBoxState}/>

    <Button style={styles.loginButton} onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this)}>
        Login
    </Button>

  </View>
  );
 },

 _handlePress(event) {
   //Get TextInput value
    var username= this.state.username;
    alert(username);
  },

 _CheckBoxState(event){
  //want to change the state from true to false or vice-versa

  }
});
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the initial state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have missed to initialize an initial state function before rendering.

```
 ...
 getInitialState: function() {
    return {username: ''};
 },
 render: function() {
  ....
 }
```

Now this.state.username should be accessable.

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue of retirving input value. :)
Can you help me to get checkbox state?

Comment: Same principle as any input. You can apply the onChange event on the checkbox. and connect it to a function where the current checkbox state gets negated. So insite the set state -> checkboxIsSelected: !this.state.checkBoxIsSelected. Of course you have to add checkboxIsSelected to your initial state also