# Undefined TextInput Value

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to submit value from text input, but when I console.log, the text that inputed before is undefined. I've already follow the instruction from [react native get TextInput value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913338/react-native-get-textinput-value?newreg=80063533e5dd45cb8d7f125ebacf826c), but still undefined.

this is state that I've made before:

```
this.state = {
  comment_value: '',
  comments: props.comments
}

submit = (args) => {
  this.props.submit(args.comment_value)
}
```

this is the the function for submitted text:

```
addComment () {

var comment_value = this.state.comment_value
console.log('success!', comment_value)
})

this.props.submit('410c8d94985511e7b308b870f44877c8', '', 'e18e4e557de511e7b664b870f44877c8')
```

}

and this is my textinput code:

```
<TextInput
underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
placeholder='Enter your comment here'
multiline numberOfLines={4}
   onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({comment_value: text})}
                value={this.state.comment_value}
                style={styles.textinput}

      />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addComment.bind(this)}>
              <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: Colors.background, width: 70}}>
                <Icon name='direction' type='entypo' color='#000'size={30} style={styles.icon} />
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should definately be working try cleaning up your code like this

```
contructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      comment_value: '',
   }
}

addComment () {
  console.log(this.state.comment_value); // should be defined
  this.props.submit(this.state.comment_value);
}

render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <TextInput
             underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
             placeholder='Enter your comment here'
             multiline numberOfLines={4}
             value={this.state.comment_value}
             onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({comment_value: text})}
             style={styles.textinput}
          />

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addComment.bind(this)}>
              <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: Colors.background, width: 70}}>
                  <Icon name='direction' type='entypo' color='#000'size={30} style={styles.icon} />
              </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
}
```

EDIT: Based on your complete code sample it seems like you're incorrectly trying to update state by doing multiple `this.state = ...` which is incorrect, to update state you have to use `this.setState({ ... })`

Comment: I wrote like this this.props.submit('410c8d94985511e7b308b870f44877c8', ' ', 'e18e4e557de511e7b664b870f44877c8') because I have to test the data posted successfully or not to the server

Comment: and yes, still undefined.

Comment: You can comment that out while you're testing whether your input is showing up or not, I made a copy of the code that I posted and it works as it should, could you post your whole page containing that code because the problem is coming from somewhere else

Comment: it doesn't work because you've lots of this.state = { ...  } essentially you're losing your   comment_value just because you're re-initialising state over and over again with different properties. You should only be initialising state once, and then updating it using this.setState({ .. })

Comment: oh, got it! but, can you write the code? I'm new in react native. and still confuse about state and this.setState:)