# How can I access the value from the text input in react native?

Tags: reactjs, native

I have the following code, I would like to get an Alert of the value that has been inputted into the text box, how can I access the value? (within alertFunction):

```
    alertFunction(text){
        Alert.alert(this.state.text);

    }    

validate(text, type) {
    num = /^[0-9]+$/
    if (type == 'telephone') {
        if (num.test(text)) {
            this.setState({
                telephoneValidate: true,
                buttonInvalid: false,
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                telephoneValidate: false,
                buttonInvalid: true,
            })
        }
    }
}




<TextInput
                style={[!this.state.telephoneValidate ? { borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'red' } : null]}
                keyboardType='numeric'
                onChangeText={(text) => this.validate(text, 'telephone')}
                value={this.state.myNumber}
                maxLength={10}  //setting limit of input
            />

            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.ButtonStyle, { backgroundColor: this.state.buttonInvalid ? '#607D8B' : '#009688' }]}
                activeOpacity={.5}
                disabled={this.state.buttonInvalid}
                onPress={this.alertFunction} 
      >

                <Text style={styles.TextStyle}>Submit</Text>

            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react native get TextInput value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913338/react-native-get-textinput-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're a bit mixed up on your state object.   For the text input component, you are binding the value to **this.state.myNumber**, but you are never attempting to adjust this value if correctly validated.  But then you are attempting to reference **this.state.text** for the alert.   You need to do a couple things.

First adjust your validate to update the state object you care about when it's valid.

```
validate(text, type){ 
   ..is valid
   this.setState({ 
      ..other items,
      myNumber: text
   });
```

This will update your state correctly, then when you want to alert, you access that property.

```
alertFunction(text){
    Alert.alert(this.state.myNumber);
    }
```